# What is the balanced equation for H2O2 + KI + dish soap

Tags: redox

I am not sure how to balance $\ce{H_2O_2 + KI + dish soap}$.   Is the dish soap involved in the equation or just to show the produced gas?  Is it a double replacement or does the $\ce{KI}$ just act as a catalyst and $\ce{H_2O_2}$ is deconstructed to $\ce{2H_2O + O_2}$? It has been a while since I had chemistry.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 4):

Ah!! The elephant toothpaste experiment.
First thing first, this reaction is actually a decomposition experiment as the following equation.

$$\ce{2H2O2 -> 2H2O + O_2}$$

Second, $\ce{KI}$ acts as a catalyst in this experiment. You also can use $\ce{MnO4}$ too as the catalyst for this experiment.

Third, the dish soap makes the product of the experiment more soapy and bubbly. So, you can see it will create look like a toothpaste. If you didn't put the dish soap, it will only look like gas bubbling out if the solution.

Comment: I haven't seen this reaction, but I'd expect a solution that was white and somewhat opaque like milk, i.e milky. I wouldn't think that the solution would get thick like a toothpaste.

Comment: It's not viscous like toothpaste. You should search one vudeo and see how is it.

Comment: Here is one such video. https://sciencebob.com/fantastic-foamy-fountain/ Really looks more like canned shaving cream and is expelled from the container.